# how do add an ajax link to an ActiveAdmin view that will trigger a function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I know how to add a link to an Active Admin. Code is below to add link:

```
row "Has Attended Orientation" do
  link_to('Accept','#')
end
```

[image]

But my requirement is that when a user clicks on `Accept`, it should show a tab to select `YES` or `NO`. If user selects `YES` then it should trigger a function. Could anyone help me, how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this,

```
link_to "Accept", { action: :<action name> }, method: :<get or post>, data: { confirm: '<Enter the message you want>' }
```

I have added explanation enclosed within <>. Please put in code according to your need.